# How To Create Draggable and Drappable List Of Controls?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, drag-and-drop, winrt-xaml

I have a `ItemControl` and i set `ItemPanel` Property to Horizontal `StackPanel` and I Bound it to `ObservableCollection` of Icons.Now I Wanna user be able to remove icons with drag drop them to out of `ItemControl` and also can change items positions with each other by drag and Drop.
(Look likes MacOSX DocBar).Can i do this with above controls ,if yes,please tell me how.if not,i appreciate to tell me i should use which controls and how

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to with your own inherited version of the controls. Microsoft writes their controls in a way to allow for easy inheriting and overriding of behavior.

It should be similar to what's done here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7841/Drag-and-Drop-Treeview-control

You want to watch events like DragStart, and DragLeave, and when it's not over your control and drop is performed do your operation.

More information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za0zx9y0.aspx

Good luck.